I have a Canon EOS 50D, and my lens (EFS 18-200 mm) just broke. What should I replace?
I'm not sure how much the body of a camera impacts the quality of a photo. I'm not new to photography but I am very new to photography gear. Replacing the lens is about 150 on ebay.

Is it worth it to get a whole new camera, considering the camera body is from 2008?

Should I replace the lens with the same model I had before, or is there a better value lens on the market?

The lens is no longer offered repairs by Canon. Is it worth it to try and get it fixed by a 3rd party? A ribbon cable on the (motherboard?) is broken and the zoom twisty thing is jammed.



If the lens is broken because you dropped the camera with the lens attached, you may want to replace the camera anyway because the mount could be slightly bent. Repairing the lens will be more expensive than finding a used one.


Is it worth it to get a whole new camera, considering the camera body is from 2008?

My usual response here - do you understand how your camera is limiting your photography? If the answer is "no", keep your current camera until you do.

Should I replace the lens with the same model I had before, or is there a better value lens on the market?

All lenses are good value for their intended use case. If what you want is a lens with a large zoom range with relatively slow speed and relatively poor image quality, then get another EF-S 18-200. If you want something else, buy something else.

Is it worth it to try and get it fixed by a 3rd party?

Almost certainly not. Just buy a second-hand one.

I agree with Kendall's statement regarding changing your camera. Nothing to add to it.
Regarding changing the lens:
I suppose you would want to replace your 18-200 with a comparable superzoom lens.
In the EFS mount I would suggest the 18-135 stm if you can live with a shorter zoom.
Usually a less extreme zoom range implies a better image quality (mind, within limits, I don't see much difference in IQ between the 18-55 stm and the 18-135 stm).
The 18-135 stm is the lens I usually bring around when don't want to be encumbered by many lenses. In general photography I don't see a substantial quality difference to the famed 17-55.
Of course it is not a fast lens. It's also not so good in low light. It works best on cameras that have dual pixel technology for focusing (starting from the 70D model) but should work fine on yours too.
On the used market you should be able to find it for around 150-180 USD. I got mine for 170.
Another option would be a 18-55 stm and a 55-250 stm. This last one is a very good lens for the price considering it's long zoom. Stays sharp all through the range.This option may be a bit more expensive though.
I thought it would be nice to add some samples taken with my 80D + 18-135 STM: (i can't link the image, just the page)
Eagle
https://www.clickasnap.com/profile/ddrake/photo/01EZ0YH9YGRRJYMTFQT5C4FZ73
San Carlone statue, Arona
https://www.clickasnap.com/profile/ddrake/photo/01F7DKVE9GM7J1B1CSFEP07PXC
Country Church @135
https://www.clickasnap.com/profile/ddrake/photo/01FX1CS7307T4MPSKY824Y035S
Flowers, shallow depth of field
https://www.clickasnap.com/profile/ddrake/photo/01F7DHG81G82NXSV3V5RQ27S2N


Is it worth it to get a whole new camera, considering the camera body is from 2008?

Depends on what "worth it" means to you. It is likely that if you replace it, it's going to cost a whole lot more than the replacement price of the lens. And it also depends on how much you need/want features that have come along since 2008. I would like some of those features, but I still shoot with a 50D upon occasion and don't really find anything sorely lacking for my use cases. But I have a half dozen different lenses, some of them pro-quality Ls, a tripod, and lighting gear to use with my 50D.  And I have a smaller micro four-thirds mirrorless setup if I want to go light.

Should I replace the lens with the same model I had before, or is there a better value lens on the market?

Same answer. It depends on how you define "better value". Superzoom lenses like the EF-S 18-200 tend to be a "jack of all trades" lens with optical performance compromises so they can be convenient and cover that huge zoom range.  For what it is, it's kind of amazing. But vs. more limited zoom range lenses, the performance isn't quite as high.  Are you willing to take advantage of the ability to change lenses at the cost of more stuff to lug about and greater inconvenience?
You could get bigger max. apertures and smaller lenses with some fast primes like the EF 50mm f/1.8 STM or EF-S 24mm f/2.8 STM. You could go wider with an EF-S 10-18 or Tamron 11-20/2.8.  You could get more reach by replacing with an 18-55 and the 55-250 IS STM.  What's the goal? What do you wish your 18-200 did that it doesn't?  Or is the 18-200 ideally suited for what you want to shoot?

The lens is no longer offered repairs by Canon. Is it worth it to try and get it fixed by a 3rd party?

No. It would very likely cost more than the replacement price of another copy.
